# Why is this basic ajax call giving me a 400 and not firing to the controller?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

This is only a problem for me in my newest dot net core 2 web app, it works in previous dot net apps with no issue.

I have a custom javascript file with paths to various servers that my site is hosted on(mainly dev, test, live).

My ajax call looks like the following:

```
var gameid = '@Html.Raw(Model.Id)';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url() + "UserGames/HasGame?id=" +gameid,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (req, status, err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
        }
    });
```

The url() in question is simply looking at my local server while testing(*please note, this port has been edited, it is correct):

```
function url() {
return "https://localhost:4432/";
}
```

The error is not firing as it isnt even reaching the controller function being used.

I'm absolutely bemused as to why this isnt working, i could understand if i was getting some sort of error back, but i have used ajax calls in all of my apps and not had this problem at all until using core 2.

Has anything changed that may have affected the way you use ajax calls?

Method that is trying to fire, but i mentioned, it isnt hitting the controller(NOTE: the method does have code in it, it just isnt hitting the controller in the first place)

```
[HttpGet]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> HasGame(int id)
{
    //stuff in here
}
```

Comment: Did you decorate the HasGame method with [HttpGet] annotation?

Comment: Would you like share action method . Meanwhile you can use POST.

Comment: [Http status 400 = Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400). The controller is found but the passed in parameters are not valid. You are thinking of 404 which is Not Found. So either your question has the wrong status code listed **OR** you are barking up the wrong tree (server code failing for other reasons).

Comment: Can you explain further please, i have posted all of the relevant code, i have put a breakpoint on the controller, and it does not seem to hit it. I understand what you are saying, and i wouldnt be surprised if i was missing something stupidly obvious, but i cant seem to see it.

Comment: `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` could be the problem as this is usually not supported on HttpGet. This attribute is used for modifying verbs like Put/Delete/Post etc.

Comment: 1). You do not hard code the url like that - use `url: '@Url.Action("HasGame", "UserGames")` and `data: { id: gameid },` to add the query string. 2) Your not passing the antiforgery token which would cause an error, but you do not need `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on a GET method, so remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this issue, i managed to fix it by doing the following to both the call and the controller:

```
type: 'GET',
url: '@Url.Action("HasGame", "UserGames")',
data: {id : gameid},
```

And the controller in core 2 does not seem to like you declaring [HttpGet] at all, so i removed that also.

Thanks for all the help provided.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a **400 (Bad Request**) response because the framework expects the `RequestVerificationToken` as part of the request.The framework uses this to prevent possible CSRF attacks. If your request does not have this information, the framework will return the **400** bad request. Your current code is not sending it.

You can fix it by explicitly send that `RequestVerificationToken`

The form tag helper automatically creates a hidden input with name atttribute value `__RequestVerificationToken` and stores the token as the value of the hidden input.

```
var token = $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
var gameid = '@Html.Raw(Model.Id)';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url() + "UserGames/HasGame?id=" +gameid,
    headers:{ "RequestVerificationToken": token },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (req, status, err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
    }
});
```

In the above example, we are using some jQuery code to get the input element with name `__RequestVerificationToken` and reading the value of it. A more robust approach would be injecting the `IAntiforgery` implementation to the view and using the `GetAndStoreTokens` method.

We will be injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` to the view. So make sure it is wired up with DI properly. Add this line to your Startup classes' `ConfigureServices` method.

```
services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Now in your view, you can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and `IAntiforgery` and then call the `GetAndStoreTokens` to get the token. Here i wrapped that into a helper function.

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContext
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions{
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext.HttpContext).RequestToken;
    }
}
```

Now later in my js, i can call this method inside my javascript code instead of using jQuery to get the input value.

```
var token = "@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()";
var gameid = '@Html.Raw(Model.Id)';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url() + "UserGames/HasGame?id=" +gameid,
    headers:{ "RequestVerificationToken": token },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (req, status, err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
    }
});
```

**Or** Simply remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute decoration from the action method, which excludes this check.

I recommend you to take advantage of the`[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` method. Send the token as part of your request(first approach)

Comment: Even with the token added, it still isnt hitting the controller action. And none of my other actions on the controller are sending this across(they are form submits rather than ajax requests)

Comment: Form submits will automatically send this token as it is part of the form data. In your ajax call, you are not sending the form data (serialized form), instead doing  a GET request with query string.

Comment: What is happening with the token code ? Are you still getting 400 response ?

Comment: yes, even if i remove the token from the controller, i am still getting the same issue, which is why i cant really work out what is wrong

Comment: Do you have some other middle where which is returning 400 ?

Comment: no, this is meant to fire when the page loads, it is set up correctly as I can fire alerts and other things before the call, and after.